# Read in a .txt file and delete line elements

Tags: r

I have a .txt file that contains values and is tab seperated. It looks like this:

```
G-clef      E1,E1,B0,G0 E1  E1  E1  E1  F1,C#1,A0   G1  A1  G1,C#1  G1,D1,C#1   C#2 B1,F1   C#2 C#2,G1,E1   C#1 C#1 C#1 C#1 C#1 C#1 B0  C#1 D1  E1,C#1,A0   F1  G1,D1,B0    G1
```

What I would like to now is the following:

- Read in all the values
- Delete the first two items of the list
- Print the items of the list

Therefore I try:

```
con <- file("outfile.txt","r")
lines <- readLines(con)

for(line in lines){
 fields = strsplit(list, "\t")
 fields = fields[-c(0,1)]

 for(f in fields){
  print(f)
 }
}
```

But this does not give me any output. Any thoughts where I go wrong?

Comment: Try `\\t` rather than `\t` in the `strsplit` function.  Also `strsplit` produces a list (of length 1 in this case), so the next line should be `fields[[1]][-c(1,2)]` (R indexes start at 1 not 0)

Comment: Can you maybe show the ideal output? Might be more helpful...